# Margin in Word and Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I need Excel sheet in Word (for calculate). I input by Insert / Object / Microsoft Excel Sheet. But I have problem with margin (via screenshot) and I dont know how I can set it?

[image]

I have Word 2011 for Mac!

Comment: Can you not resize the object by dragging the black nodes on the boundary? Or do you want to do something different?

Comment: No, I cant. If I dragging the black notes, I resize all table. And if I takes with Shift, Cmd, alt - nothing change...